# Is using multiple .env files bad practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, environment-variables, password-protection

I need to run tests in different environments : `DEV`, `STAGING`, `PRODUCTION`.
And needless to say, the environment variables/secrets for the above environments would obviously be different.

I quick solution would be to have an env file for each environment like `dev.env`, `staging.env` & `prod.env`

But according to the docs of popular dotEnv npm package and 12 Factor app, it is not recommended to have multiple `.env` files in your repo.

Please give me a practical solution of managing env vars for multiple environments.

- https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files
- https://12factor.net/config

Comment: _In your repo_? But `.env` files hold secrets like API keys and crypto hashes, they're not supposed to be commited and part of your repo. The whole point of `.env` files is to have one per machine, so you can precisely have content in them depending on the machine/environment : dev, staging, production. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @JeremyThille one should not put secrets in an `.env` file assuming they are checked in the repo. Secrets should be handled separately & securely by a dedicated mechanism! Now, not checking env files into a repo creates a different problem: where do we keep it? how do we back it up? how do we track changes?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly what they're writing here:

**Should I have multiple .env files?**

> No. We strongly recommend against having a "main" .env file and an "environment" .env file like .env.test. Your config should vary between deploys, and you should not be sharing values between environments.

This doesn't mean that you shouldn't have multiple env files, but rather that you shouldn't have one `main.env` file with all the default configuration and additional env files (one per environment) that inherit from `main.env` and override certain values.

The reason why it's not recommended is that with such a configuration it's difficult to understand "where a specific value is coming from?" (from which one of the following: main-env-file, specific-env-file, env-variable, code-default and etc).

That said, if you create multiple env files without such a "main" this means that you'll need to duplicate many of the values all over the different env files, which is better because of explicitness, but has the downside of duplication/verbosity.

Configuration is not trivial IMO and while you have only a small project it doesn't matter much how you choose to implement, but if we're talking about something more critical like a company's product, then there are many solutions available out there, some are open-source and free, some cost money, but it's worth doing your research and figure out which one provides you the benefits that are more meaningful to your use-case.

Some of the more popular tools are: [Puppet](https://puppet.com/), [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), and [Chef](https://www.chef.io/products/chef-infra).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's better to have multiple .env in your project.

For example in Symfony, we can configure multiple environment for our project, example: local, dev, prod. it's purpose is to  have a more clean and readable code.

I'm not sure about over technologies but you can read a little bit about .env in this Symfony article(no need to be a crack in symfony): https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#config-dot-env